# Recibir valor Fecha en un modal y campo date

Tags: php, sql, ajax, modal

sigo con las ediciones de registros sobre modales.
Bien, me encuentro que al pasar los datos al modal los recibo todo bien menos la fecha que no me sale marcada la de la BD.

Vereis sigo mandando los datos como siempre:

**Añadiendo el id mando los campos almodal**

```
<td class="tdfgaz" id="Fecha<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Fecha']; ?></td>
```

**Recibo los datos en el modal de este modo**
Los campos que no consigo sacar bien son #eFecha y #eVencimiento

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.pedido', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                var Idp=$('#Idp'+id).text();
                var Estado=$('#select2-1'+id).children('span').first().text();
                var Numero=$('#Numero'+id).text();
                var Fecha=$('#Fecha'+id).text();
                var Vencimiento=$('#Vencimiento'+id).text();
                var Producto=$('#Producto'+id).text();
                var Total=$('#Total'+id).text();
                var Tipo=$('#select2-4'+id).children('span').first().text();
                var Ref=$('#select2-3'+id).children('span').first().text();

                $('#pedido').modal('show');
                $('#eIdp').val(Idp);
                $('#eNumero').val(Numero);
                $('#eFecha').val(Fecha);
                $('#eVencimiento').val(Vencimiento);
                $('#eProducto').val(Producto);
                $('#eTotal').val(Total);


                //alert(Estado);
                if(Estado == 'Pagado')
                  $('select#select2-1').val('1').trigger('change');
                else
                  $('select#select2-1').val('0').trigger('change');

                if(Tipo == 'Alquiler')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('1').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Comprada')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('2').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Exp.Compartida')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('3').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Alq. Opción a compra')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('5').trigger('change');


                if(Ref == 'Sin asignar')
                  $('select#select2-3').val('0').trigger('change');
                else
                  $('select#select2-3').val('').trigger('change');

                 });
             });
    </script>
```

**Y así imprimo el valor en los value normalmente**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii corpaddate" id="eFecha" name="eFecha">
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Pueba el ejemplo, para que veas como funciona.

```js
var fecha = document.getElementById("Fecha25").textContent;
console.log('fecha '+fecha);
var res = fecha.split("/");
var fechaFormateada = res[2] + "-" + res[1] + "-" + res[0];
console.log('fecha formateada '+fechaFormateada);
document.getElementById('eFecha').value = fechaFormateada;
```

```html
<span id="Fecha25">04/05/2018</span>
<br />
<input type="date" id="eFecha" value='' />
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82558/discussion-on-answer-by-santiago-celada-gonzalez-recibir-valor-fecha-en-un-modal).